# Complex relations among drawing order of the nodes in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create non-trivial relations between the zPosition among SpriteKit nodes. For example, suppose this is a game scene:

[image]

As you can see, the triangles have precedence over the circles, the circles have precedence over the squares, and the squares have precedence over the triangles. Just like rock paper scissors.

Its clear to me that is impossible to define these relations just by setting different `.zPosition` for different kind of nodes. So my question is: Is there a way to do this in SpriteKit?

*edit*: as @EmilioPelaez pointed out, there would be a problem if 3 or more nodes overlap, so I'm already assuming that no such overlaps would happen.

Comment: What will happen if a triangle, a square and a circle are all on the same position, which one should be drawn?

Comment: good point. I might need to define some global ordering for those cases. But I think that for my game no overlaps would occur. Let me edit the question for that matter.

Comment: You're can either programmatically set `zPosition` for shapes that occupy the same spot in some way, depending on your game logic, or you can perhaps have pre-rendered composite pairs that have the relationship baked in.  What makes sense or is easiest depends on how the game is supposed to be played, whether shapes can move around, etc.

Comment: It's not possible as I think there is a contradiction with what you're trying to achieve.  Consider the square-circle pairing shown above (topmost image). If you add a triangle, the triangle will try to go behind the square, but also try to go above the circle. This isn't possible as it is attempting to be behind the square *and* on top of the square at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this in SpriteKit by using an `SKCropNode`.

For each triangle, square and circle the scene will contain one respective node as it's own child.
Triangles will have a `zPosition` of 0, squares a `zPosition` of 1 and circles a `zPosition` of 2.

The scene will also contain an `SKCropNode`, subsequently referred to as `cropNode`.
This node will be used to display those parts of the triangles which are covered up by circles.
The `maskNode` property of `cropNode` will be set to an `SKNode` which we will call `maskNode`.

For each circle we will add another `SKSpriteNode` as a child to `maskNode`, whose position and other properties will be synchronized to the original circle.
Similarly for each triangle a synchronized `SKSpriteNode` will be added as a child to `cropNode`.

When the `cropNode` is positioned at the scene's origin and is drawn above all other triangles, squares and circles in the scene, the desired effect can be achieved.

It is not defined by the rules what should happen for pixels of the scene in which all three types of nodes overlap.
In this implementation the triangles will be drawn above everything else.

The following code defines a scene which implements this:

```swift
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

fileprivate let ZTRIANGLE: CGFloat = 0
fileprivate let ZSQUARE: CGFloat = 1
fileprivate let ZCIRCLE: CGFloat = 2
fileprivate let ZABOVEALL: CGFloat = 3

// MARK: - Nodes
class DoubleNode: SKSpriteNode {
    fileprivate let doubleNode: SKSpriteNode

    override var position: CGPoint {
        didSet {
            self.synchronizePosition()
        }
    }
    override var size: CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.synchronizeSize()
        }
    }
    override var color: UIColor {
        didSet {
            self.synchronizeColor()
        }
    }
    override var colorBlendFactor: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            self.synchronizeColorBlendFactor()
        }
    }
    override var isHidden: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.synchronizeHidden()
        }
    }

    override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        self.doubleNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    func getDoubleNode() -> SKSpriteNode {
        return self.doubleNode
    }

    override func removeFromParent() {
        self.doubleNode.removeFromParent()
        super.removeFromParent()
    }



    func synchronizeAll() {
        self.synchronizePosition()
        self.synchronizeSize()
        self.synchronizeColorBlendFactor()
        self.synchronizeColor()
        self.synchronizeHidden()
    }

    func synchronizePosition() {
        if let selfParent = self.parent, let doubleParent = doubleNode.parent {
            self.doubleNode.position = selfParent.convert(self.position, to: doubleParent)
        } else {
            self.doubleNode.position = self.position
        }
    }

    func synchronizeSize() {
        self.doubleNode.size = self.size
    }

    func synchronizeColorBlendFactor() {
        self.doubleNode.colorBlendFactor = self.colorBlendFactor
    }

    func synchronizeColor() {
        self.doubleNode.color = self.color
    }

    func synchronizeHidden() {
        self.doubleNode.isHidden = self.isHidden
    }
}


class Circle: DoubleNode {
    // Definition of circle node ...
}

class Square: DoubleNode {
    // Definition of square node ...
}

class Triangle: DoubleNode {
    // Definition of triangle node ...
}






// MARK: - Scene
fileprivate extension SKNode {
    func getAncestors() -> [SKNode] {
        var res: [SKNode] = []

        var node = self
        while let parent = node.parent {
            res.append(parent)
            node = parent
        }

        return res
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKSceneDelegate {
    fileprivate var selectedNode: SKNode? = nil

    fileprivate let cropNode: SKCropNode = SKCropNode()
    fileprivate let maskNode: SKNode = SKNode()

    fileprivate var nodesToSynchronize: [DoubleNode] = []

    // MARK: - Initialization
    override init() {
        super.init(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
        self.setup()
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.setup()
    }

    fileprivate func setup() {
        cropNode.zPosition = ZABOVEALL
        cropNode.maskNode = maskNode
        self.addChild(cropNode)

        self.delegate = self
    }





    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        self.size = view.frame.size

        self.backgroundColor = .white

        for i in 0..<5 {
            let node = Triangle(size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
            node.position = CGPoint(x: i * 50 + 50, y: 50)
            node.zPosition = ZTRIANGLE
            self.addChild(node)
        }

        for i in 0..<5 {
            let node = Circle(size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
            node.position = CGPoint(x: i * 50 + 50, y: 100)
            node.zPosition = ZCIRCLE
            self.addChild(node)
        }

        for i in 0..<5 {
            let node = Square(size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
            node.position = CGPoint(x: i * 50 + 50, y: 150)
            node.zPosition = ZSQUARE
            self.addChild(node)
        }

    }

    override func addChild(_ node: SKNode) {
        super.addChild(node)
        if let circleNode = node as? Circle {
            self.maskNode.addChild(circleNode.getDoubleNode())
        } else if let triangleNode = node as? Triangle {
            self.cropNode.addChild(triangleNode.getDoubleNode())
        }
        if let node = node as? DoubleNode {
            self.nodesToSynchronize.append(node)
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        
    }

    override func didEvaluateActions() {
        // This is necessary to ensure that all doubleNodes are synchronized after evaluating actions
        for node in self.nodesToSynchronize {
            if node.hasActions() {
                node.synchronizeAll()
            }
        }
    }



    // MARK: Touches
    /*
     * This code is responsible for allowing the nodes to be moved by touches.
     * It can be removed without affecting the desired effect.
    */
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        guard touches.count == 1 else {
            return
        }
        guard let view = self.view else {
            return
        }
        let touch = touches.first!
        self.selectedNode = self.nodes(at: self.convertPoint(fromView: touch.location(in: view)))
            .first(where: {node in
                // This is necessary to prevent child nodes of self.cropNode to become a selectedNode
                return !node.getAncestors().contains(self.cropNode)
        })
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        guard touches.count == 1 else {
            return
        }
        guard let view = self.view else {
            return
        }
        guard let selectedNode = selectedNode else {
            return
        }
        let touch = touches.first!
        let viewPos = touch.location(in: view)
        let scenePos = self.convertPoint(fromView: viewPos)
        guard let parentPos = selectedNode.parent?.convert(scenePos, from: self) else {
            return
        }
        selectedNode.position = parentPos
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.selectedNode = nil
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        self.selectedNode = nil
    }
}
```